# Slingscold launcher finds nothing

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, slingshot-launcher

Trying to use [Slingscold launcher](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/06/slingscold-launcher-is-now-available.html) in Linux Mint Xfce Qiana -  it should look something like the search in Gnome Shell

[image]

but it finds nothing and is just empty:

[image]

Does it need some other dependency to operate?

---

(At the same time the Whiskermenu works fine, just like any other search app that I tried, including XFDashboard, which is very similar to the search in Gnome and to Slingscold.)

Comment: Try running `slingscold` from terminal and see if any output appears. I just managed to build a version for fedora, the problem there being it needs a old version of [`libgnome-menu`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libgnome-menu-3-0). Other than that, it could be that on Mint `mintstick` breaks it: http://sourceforge.net/projects/slingscold/reviews/?sort=created_date&stars=0#reviews-n-ratings

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, try using one of Mint-X icon sets (not default one or gnome one). Also "my-mint-elementary" icon set works fine.